# Inherited drupal site that makes apps

Tags: drupal

I inherited a site that is built on Drupal platform. It is used to create mobile apps and then the back end gives a url to submit to the Apple/Google Play store.

My question is how on earth do I figure out what tool/suite/mod the original person use to set this up?

When I am logged in to the back end all I see are the regular Drupal back end editing tools. I can edit aspects of the pages in the app, but as a learning process, how do I track down how this starts?

To sum it up, my drupal site makes apps. How do I know what utility was used to make them or how can I make edits?

Comment: I think it is quite early to be posting that question - instead, it is equally important that you search first and do some research before posting your question. Also include what you have tried and indicate the problem(s) you are experiencing. As it is, you did not demonstrate that you have tried anything yet - so please consult whatever online resources, project documentation, etc to get up to speed - and if you should encounter programming related problems, please come back and post a more specific question.

Comment: i dont have any documentation regarding how this was set up. it was dropped into my lap. i have gone though the live backend extensively and i see how to make changes to content in the existing apps, but i dont understand or see how to make a new app. that's what i was trying to ask, how to do i now what tool/app is begin used to make this.

Comment: How does the app get from the Drupal site to the app store?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is the URL that you say the app produces. Somewhere in your Drupal site's codebase there will be code that defines this URL, and code that responds to it. What that code looks like depends on which version of Drupal you are on.

Comment: i am now not sure if the system produces this url or if it is just put in. i have found many apps that have a blank url for the google/apple store yet they are there available as apps, so i think it is just added in to keep a record of.